# Is "since so long" correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, conjunctions, time

> Because of our negligence towards the issue since so long, ...

Am I using this correctly? I want to convey something like *1-2 months ago* or *since around September*.

Comment: `for so long` sounds much more natural to me.

Comment: In the first place, the usual expression is "for so long," not "since so long." Second, a couple of months may or may not represent a long time.

Comment: @Robusto I didn't use "for so long" for that reason. Should I still go with it?

Comment: The correct expression is "for so long" or "since September", not "since so long"

Comment: If you simply want to indicate an indeterminate length of time which isn't going to be misinterpreted as "for so long" might be, you could use "for however long." That's a contraction of "for however long we have been doing that" which is in common usage and understood in British English, at least. It's a bit colloquial, but you have given no context.

Comment: whether 1-2 months constitutes a long time is completely subjective.  1-2 months is long time to go without food.

Answer (score 4):

When used in a "time-related" context (as opposed to when it means *because*), the word *since* is invariably followed by a reference to *an actual time (or event) in the past*. For example,...

> I've been working *since **this morning.***
>   I've been working *since **I got up.***

You might just about get away with...

> I've been living here [since so long **ago**.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22since%20so%20long%20ago%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22since%20so%20long%20ago%22&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&ei=ftirUPCEAaad0AW8kIFA&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=671eb1a037295d38&bpcl=38897761&biw=1197&bih=867)

...but even adding *ago* wouldn't make OP's example acceptable to me (though it might for some).

As noted in various comments, the normal usage here would be ***for*** so long.

---

Exactly how long ago *so long* might be is totally subjective. In some contexts, you might use it to refer back to a time less than an hour ago. In other contexts, people might say that several months (or even years, decades, or centuries) wasn't actually ***so*** long ago.

Comment: I think "since so long ago" connotes a very long time indeed. "I've been living here since so long ago [that I can't remember where I lived before moving here]." Cf "I've been living here since so short a time ago [that I don't know where the nearest post-box is]."

Comment: @Andrew: My Google Books link has just 25 instances of the word sequence *"since so long ago"*, and out of those I can only see maybe 3 or 4 used the way OP asks about (i.e. - without even the supporting word *"ago"*). I don't see that adding *"ago"* makes any difference to the length of time you're talking about, but I can see why it makes the construction slightly more acceptable. For example, in *"It's been going on since **so long ago that I can't remember**"* the temporal referent could be replaced by *"**last year**"*, since (!?) they're both valid nouns meaning "a time in the past".

Answer (score 0):

One can say “since long ago” understandably and idiomatically, or “for so long” as mentioned in comments,  but “since so long” is too awkward for words.  As FumbleFingers noted in a comment, “since so long ago” is rare in Google Books.  Looking at another corpus –    [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/) with its approximately 14 million questions, and several times that many answers and comments –  “[since so long](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com/questions+%22since+so+long%22+-newest+-recently)” shows up only 9 times (as of Dec. 2012).  Instead, the term of art on SO is the curious “[since long time](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com/questions+%22me+since+long+time%22+-newest+-recently#q=site:stackoverflow.com/questions+%22since+long+time%22+-newest+-recently&hl=en&tbo=d&ei=ZYi_UMLfCuf7iwKEgoHgDA&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=23b8333ec4c56233&bpcl=39468505&biw=1053&bih=579)”, which appears about 1150 times.  For example, in questions [#9590114](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590114/importance-of-pca-or-svd-in-machine-learning) line 4, [#12569673](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569673/identifying-icmpv6-type) line 11,  and [#13727862](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727862/clarification-about-data-types-in-python) line 1,  we see

> • I am trying to think (since long time) but I am not able to guess why is it so.
>   • This problem is bugging me since long time. Thanks.
>   • One thing has been fascinating me since long time. In languages like c [...]